# Customizing text on Spinner control

Tags: android

I've seen some answers to questions about how to specify a custom layout for a spinner's pop-up list, but what I want to do is to customize the text on the Spinner control itself, such the "setText..." methods that you can call for a Button (TextView subclass).

Is there any way to do this? What I'm trying to do is to make my own Spinner design as I have for some of the other controls so it takes up less space and matches the general look of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I want to do is to customize the text on the Spinner control itself, such the "setText..." methods that you can call for a Button

There is no text on the `Spinner` control itself.

If you are referring to the `View` that is shown when a `Spinner` is closed (i.e., normal state), that is handled by your `SpinnerAdapter`, either via the layout you provide in the constructor, or via your overridden `getView()`.

Comment: I thought that the layout in the constructor controlled the appearance of the list that pops up when you click the spinner. What I want to do is to customize the appearance of the spinner when the list is closed, similar to what you can do with a button by setting the button's background image.

Comment: @gordonwd: "I thought that the layout in the constructor controlled the appearance of the list that pops up when you click the spinner." -- no, that is controlled by `getDropDownView()` on your `SpinnerAdapter`.